# How to cast an integer array to a String array without creating separate array of strings and adding individually casted int array items to it?

Tags: java, arrays, string, casting

```
int[] locations = {ran1,ran2,ran3};
String positions = locations.toString();
```

When cast this way, it casts the `int[]` into a String but not to `String[]`. I tried casting individual integers ran1, ran2, ran3 into String primitives and then adding them to the different `String[]` to use in the code, but why an array got cast into only the primitive String but not into an array. Am I using the wrong syntax to cast an entire `int[]` to `String[]`? Is there any other method to cast an entire array?

Comment: `IntStream.of(locations).mapToObj(Integer::toString).toArray(String[]::new)`.

Comment: You can't "cast" an array of Integers to be an array of Strings, because an Integer is not a String.  You have no choice but to make a second array and insert the individual Integer-converted-to-String values. Your only choice is in how to code the making and populating of the second array.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "cast" a `int[]` to a `String[]` (neither can you "cast" an `int` to a `String`): what you can and have to do is "convert".

To convert from `int` to `String` you can use `Integer#toString()` method.

To convert an array, there's no built-in method but you can do as suggested in a comment:

```java
IntStream.of(locations).mapToObj(Integer::toString).toArray(String[]::new)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  int arr[]= {1,2,3,4,5,6};
  String x= Arrays.toString(arr);
```